# Gridlines that overlap with axes spines have different width from other gridlines

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'm using Seaborn to make some plots using the *whitegrid* style. After calling *despine()*, I'm seeing that the gridlines that would overlap with the axes spines have smaller linewidth than the other gridlines. But it seems like this only happens when I save the plots as pdf. I'm sharing 
three different figures with different despine configurations that show the effect.

Does anyone know why this occurs? And is there a simple fix?

[PDF plot with all spines](https://www.dropbox.com/s/digipo1xm34404r/box.pdf?dl=0)

[PDF plot that despines all axes](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z2o791i0gh9qyco/despine_bot.pdf?dl=0)

[PDF plot that despines left, top, and right axes](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9618kb4j26z3q8u/despine.pdf?dl=0)

Code:

```
splot = sns.boxplot(data=df, palette=color, whis=np.inf, width=0.5, linewidth = 0.5)                     
splot.set_ylabel('Normalized WS')                        
plt.xticks(rotation=90)                                  
plt.tight_layout()                                       
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)                      
plt.savefig('test.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what's happening here is that the grid lines are centered on the tick position, so the outer half of the extreme grid lines are not drawn because they extend past the limits of the axes.

One approach is to disable clipping for the grid lines:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="whitegrid", rc={"grid.linewidth": 5})
x = np.random.randn(100, 6)

ax = sns.boxplot(data=x)
ax.yaxis.grid(True, clip_on=False)
sns.despine(left=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My hacking solution now is to not despine the top and bottom axes and make them the same width as the gridlines. This is not ideal. If someone can point out a way to fix the root cause, I will really appreciate that.